# I keep getting a syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, python, ipython

I keep getting a syntax error with the following line of code:

```
# If the user asked for celsius then x will be a Celsius number converting to Fahrenheit number
if x = = c
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: you need to provide some more info. copypaste the exact error message as well as the surrounding code to the `==` above. BTW are you trying to check if the variable `x` contains the letter `c`? If so, use `if x=="c":`

Comment: Please show the whole code. Also: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 6):

The `= =` should be `==`

```
if x == c:
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your using `==` instead of `= =` (if its not clear)-> replace `=[SPACE]=` with `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a colon as well to removing the space.